# Java - How do Pattern and Matcher do to split a string with '|' character to a slice of sub-strings like res.sub() in python works?

Tags: java, python, string, nlp

I am working on a NLP project about keyword extraction and I am a newbie in this field. My current task is about getting phrases (sub-strings) that are split from a sentence that I process before. I implemented from a source written in Python.

```
    tmp = re.sub(stopword_pattern, '|', s.strip())
    phrases = tmp.split("|")
    for phrase in phrases:
        phrase = phrase.strip().lower()
        phrase_list.append(phrase)
```

As I read and understood, this procedure uses Regex to remove words from stopword_pattern and then replace them with '|' character from a sentence. Then, it split itself into array of strings by removing '|'. Here is an example:

From a sentence named s:  and nonstrict inequations are considered

> tmp: and|nonstrict|inequations|are|considered
>
> phrases: ['and', 'nonstrict', 'inequations', 'are', 'considered']

I translated this to Java and here what I did:

```
 sentence = sentence.trim();

        if (sentence.equals("")) {
            continue;
        }

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher matcher = stopWordsPattern.matcher(sentence);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "|");
        }

        String tempResult = sb.toString();
        String[] phrases = tempResult.split("|");
        for (String phrase : phrases) {
            phrase = phrase.trim().toLowerCase();
            phraseList.add(phrase);
        }
```

But with that code, the result is difference:

> tmp: |and||nonstrict||inequations||are||considered|
>
> phrases:[|, a, n, d, |, |, n, o, n, s, t, r, i, c, t, |, |, i, n, e, q, u, a, t, i, o, n, s, |, |, a, r, e, |, |, c, o, n, s, i, d, e, r, e, d, |]

I checked a stop_pattern from 2 codes and both are correct. My question is how to setup string pattern "|" in java, or more specifically, is how to make Pattern and Matcher in Java work like the above source from Python?

Many thanks about that!

P/s: I tried with other split string like '~' or '_'..., but they can be noised by natural sentence from human language, so I use '|'.

Comment: I tried using " | " instead of "|", it seems like the result is better but it was not I expected as in Python.

Comment: | is a special character in regex, use split(Pattern.quote("|")) if you wan't to use it

Comment: thanks Turo Oct, very nice way, I fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Turo:
| is a special character in regex, use split(Pattern.quote("|")) if you wan't to use it. Done!